# Is a map linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

For $k \in \mathbb{N}, C^k(\mathbb{R,C}) \{f:\mathbb{R \to C}; f$ is $k$ times differentiable$\},$ $C^k(\mathbb{R,C})$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$

How do I show whether

$$T:C^k(\mathbb{R,C}) \to C^{k-1}(\mathbb{R,C})\\
(Tf)(x) := df(x)/dx + 5f(x)$$

is a linear map? Also, what is the kernel of this function?

Comment: Do you know what the definition of a linear map is? Do you know what the definition of a kernel of a linear map is? Are you sure you mean $k \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hint: $(f+g)'=f'+g'$

Comment: @Stijn you're right. A linear map for vector spaces V,W ie T:V $\to$ W is a linear map if: T(u+v) = T(u)+T(v) and T($\lambda$u) = $\lambda$T(u). The kernel of T is the points satisfying T(v)= 0 where v is in V. How does this apply to functions?

Comment: Regarding LaTeX/MathJax formatting: the `$`'s *are your friend*.  I think you'll have a much easier time in the future if you check why what I did makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A map $L$ is linear if for scalar $a$ and vectors $x,y$, we have $$L(ax+y)=a L(x)+L(y).$$ You just need to verify the definition on this. The kernel of $L$ is simply $$\ker L=\{x: L(x) = 0\}$$that is, the vectors which map to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in this question, the "vectors" are the functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, with addition defined by $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and scalar multiplication defined by $(\alpha\cdot f)(x) = \alpha\cdot f(x)$.  The "zero-vector" is, correspondingly, a function of the form $z(x) = 0$.

The reason that differentiation is linear is that 
$$
\frac d{dx} (f+g)(x) = \frac d{dx} (f(x) + g(x)) = \frac d{dx} f(x) + \frac d{dx}g(x)
$$
and
$$
\frac d{dx}(\alpha \cdot f)(x) = \frac d{dx}(\alpha\cdot f(x)) = \alpha \cdot \frac d{dx}f(x)
$$
I'll leave it to you to prove that $T$ is also linear.  The kernel is the set of all functions $f$ satisfying the equation
$$
\frac {df(x)}{dx} + 5f(x) = 0
$$
for all $x$. This is just a differential equation for $f$; solve it.